# Not able to get tmp_name ($_FILES) of file in smart phone

Tags: php, arrays, file

Here, is my html form :

```
<form method="post" action="filename.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="file_upload" name="image[]" value="Upload" multiple="" type="file">
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I print $_FILES in filename.php file then I am able to get below array in PC :

```
Array
(
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sket-printed-shirt.jpg
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => image/jpeg
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => /tmp/phpSA6YF5
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 280515
    )

)
```

But getting below array in smart phones like : Motorola G4 plus , G5 plus and HTC one mini 2

```
Array
(
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sket-printed-shirt.jpg
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => image/jpeg
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

 )
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you don't have `tmp_name` there is because the upload failed with error code `1`, which indicates the file was too large. See: [upload file error codes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

> UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have increase the size in php.ini. Now, I am not able to get uploaded image array in firefox browser of Motorola G4 plus , G5 plus. Working fine in Chrome browser.